# javascript promise resolve function vs resolve anonymous function

Tags: javascript, promise

Why is this working (based on the console.log output)

```
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var test = function() {
        console.log('rrrr');
        return $timeout(function(){},100);
    }
    resolve(test());
}
```

But this is not?

```
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(function() {
        console.log('rrrr');
        return $timeout(function(){},100);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this just for the sake of example? Because neither snippet really makes sense.

Comment: What does `$timeout` return?

Comment: @torazaburo in angular it returns a Promise

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, I use the timeout to force an update in the browser layout, otherwise it doesn't render any change I have made to it until all the code has been executed. But this is not relevant for the question, it is here just because I have copy&pasted from my code

Comment: @Gerard: The point is that you should simplify the whole code to `console.log('rrr'); return Promise.resolve($timeout(function(){},100));`. Don't use the promise constructor here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the top one *calls* the test function, but the bottom one only *defines* the anonymous function.

Try this, it should work:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(function() {
        console.log('rrrr');
        return $timeout(function(){},100);
    }()); // the extra () will call your anonymous function.
}
```